# Mapbox: disable zoom on scroll, but use ctr+scroll instead

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map that I wish to integrate into a page. 
When I simply scroll over it, the map won't zoom and I can view the next content. But when I ctrl + scroll over the map, it will zoom in.

How can I do that with mapbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, where map is your map variable. Also, you can bind this event on some div, I think, not the whole window.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) 
{
    if(event.ctrlKey == true) {
        map['scrollZoom'].enable();
    }
    else {
        map['scrollZoom'].disable();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (no jquery required):

```
map.on("wheel", event => {
  if (event.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.originalEvent.metaKey) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.originalEvent.altKey) {
    return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6884